# Dropdown Menu Shifting in Firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is the URL: http://www.labeachfit.com/

The dropdown menu under "More" works fine in Google Chrome, however, it's shifting to underneath the "Home" link when in Firefox.

Anyone know what the cause could be on this one? Is Firefox ignoring something?

Is there a way to fix this without placing the dropdown menu inside the "More" element?

Comment: You may need to say a little more.  It's being dropped down under more on my first viewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS definition for `.navbar .nav li` states `display:table-cell`. It also contains `position:relative` to establish a new positioning context for the dropdown to base its absolute positioning on - this is why you would expect the dropdown underneath the `li`.

The standards however explicitly prohibit the use of `position` styling on table cells, yet are not really clear on whether this also includes non-table-cell elements that are set to act like one with `display:table-cell`. Firefox acts as if it does, and ignores the `position` declaration, thus putting the absolutely positioned child under the nearest higher positioning context - IE and Chrome both do allow it, but only to establish a new positioning context, which is why your code works fine in those browsers right now.

To solve this issue, add another subelement inside the `li`, around the `ul`, which is statically positioned inside the 'table cell', with `position:relative` - this will cause the popup to appear in the correct place.

So in a nutshell:

```
<body>
  <section style="position:relative;display:table-cell">
    <div style="position:absolute">
      This inner div will be positioned relative to the *body* in FF,
      or to the *section* in Chrome and IE.
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Fix that works on all:

```
<body>
  <section style="display:table-cell">
    <div style="position:relative">
      <div style="position:absolute">
        This inner div will be positioned relative to the section in *all*
        browsers.
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: This is built in Wordpress, so I can't really create another subelement. Any other way around it?

Comment: Nope, it's just Firefox interpreting the standards as they can be. This is the only workaround I'm aware off. Also, in Wordpress you can of course still edit the templates, so that's a non-argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set next css style ( position and float were changed):

```
 .dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    float: right;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```